# Save and minimise a notebook

Tags: notebooks

When working on a project I often have useful modules in another notebook. I like to compile these modules and then leave them available for modifications and new modules.
Here is the code I use

```
nb = SetDirectory[];
dir = "C:\\All\\Mathematica\\Standard Modules";
SetDirectory[dir];
fn = FileNames[];
fn = FileNameJoin[{dir, fn[[-1]]}];
nb1 = NotebookOpen[fn];
SelectionMove[nb1, All, Notebook]
SelectionEvaluate[nb1];
NotebookSave[nb1];
SetDirectory[nb]
```

Two minor things I would like to improve:

1. Minimise the notebook so that it is open but just an icon in the toolbar.
2. Make the `NotebookSave[]`in the above list work. Why does Mathematica make me save again even if I have not made any changes?
   Version 13 for Windows

Thanks

Comment: You might want to check out `NotebookEvaluate`.  `SelectionEvaluate` is asynchronous.  i.e., it is just putting cells in the evaluation queue.

Comment: @ihojnicki I am looking for a command that would look like NotebookMinimise or similar. Do you know of one?

Comment: There is no documented way to minimize and restore windows.

Comment: @ihojnicki Good to know that there is no way. Thanks.